# Extra space in statement details in team billing

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams

When being billed for teams there is an extra space between the s and the rest of the word as shown:

[image]

Comment: Circle not red nor freehand, booooooooo!

Comment: How did this get so many upvotes with this green oval?

Comment: Are they paying you for your QA work yet? They should be.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Maybe they could comp him a free year of Teams...

Comment: @All - Just trying to build good software for ALL of us!

Comment: @JonH can you forward the email to me? I have history of what was sent but the raw text here doesn't have any space and I wanna see what's going on

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the heads up, I *think* this is now fixed but I need the raw email from you to verify that is the case.

**UPDATE**

I've triple-checked the template and passed it through the rendering suite we have configured on Litmus and I can't repro this. Thanks for the assistance with digging in here. I'm gonna assume that it got fixed somewhere along the way and mark this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Comment: The original email?  Where can / do I send it to?

Comment: Can you send the raw email (headers & content) to dward@ and I'll dig a little further

Comment: Should be in your inbox in 3...2...1...